# ubuntu pdf form calculation

Tags: javascript, linux, ubuntu, pdf

I'm having problem with Ubuntu filling PDF form that has calculation function in it. It won't calculated but in Windows, it's work fine.
In Ubuntu, I use Evince (Document Preview) on PDF file which is default for unity.

Can anyone help me with this?

PDF Demo: [Normal with Calc](https://goo.gl/y809fL), 
[Calc with JavaScript](http://tinyurl.com/njv6v7s)

Neither files are working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79049/does-evince-support-javascript-in-pdf-files), there is no support of JavaScript in Evince. Therefore, it is no surprise that your forms do not work. Besides finding a PDF viewer which does support JavaScript (such as Adobe Reader, if there is a version for Ubuntu at all; otherwise use a virtual machine), there is not much you can do about this.

If you are the forms owner, and chances that your users have a PDF viewer which is too dumb for the forms, you can set them up to open for the dumb viewer (making them simply fillable, but no logic), display a message that the form won't be smart, and then have a document-level JavaScript which activates the smart functions, and hides the message.

Such an approach is recommended when your forms are very likely to be used on mobile devices, because there are only few PDF viewers which support (Acrobat) JavaScript, and the ones which do, do so in a limited way.

Comment: Thanks for you respone.